# Ragtag apparently not working?

Tags: vim

I am currently trying to use ragtag to close some of my html tags in ERB files. However, pressing something like (C-X)/ (which I interpret to be , "CONTROL" + "uppercase X" + "/") it just prints the / to the buffer. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think `X` should be interpreted as "uppercase x" (`Shift`+`x` or `<S-x>`), here. Try `Ctrl`+`x`+`/` (lowercase x), instead.

Comment: doesn't appear to work - although it is worth mentioning that it no longer prints to the buffer!

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you're in the correct mode. The (Ctrl-X) key mappings of ragtag.vim only work in "insert" mode, which is a bit non-intuitive since most text manipulation in Vim is done in "normal" mode.

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure in your `.vimrc` file, you have the line

```
let g:ragtag_global_maps = 1
```

This gives you access to the ragtag key mappings as in `<C-X>/` or `<C-X><space>`

Next, be sure to note that the available ragtag functions available to you depends on the type of file you're in.  For instance, when you're in a standard `.rb` file, you only get a few features, whereas if you open an `erb` file, you get all the goodies.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying timeoutlen and ttimeoutlen to something bigger, or delete any lines you have set in your .vimrc. The default value should be sufficient for ragtag to work.